# Convert Emgu.Mat to ushort[]

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I would like to find out the fastest way to convert 16bit Emgu Mat to ushort array in the C#. Right now I am using

```
ushort[] outputArray = new ushort[(int)emguMat.Total];
emguMat.CopyTo(outputArray);
```

But this solution is copying the data and I believe that there must be a way how to do it without copying the data.

The `Mat` data are continuous (according to the property `Mat.IsContinuous`) so if I understand it right, the part of the data in the heap memory does not need any change so all I have to do is somehow use the pointer to these data to create the ushort array.

Comment: Does this help? http://answers.opencv.org/question/113839/convert-mat-to-16-bit-int/